# Seek a SMTP Server hiding sender IP

Tags: email, smtp

Is there any SMTP mail server (either web service or local software) that does not record sender's IP in the header?

**UPDATE**:

What I have is a free version of Axigen mail server installed on my PC. I use this server to send emails to an account somewhere else which I can login and read the received emails. When I review the headers and sender chain of emails in this account, I see my ISP valid IP address plus my computer name. I want to remove the sender's IP from that.

Comment: Generally, the sender IP is added by the *receiving* MTA, not the sender.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thanks for response. Is there an way to do that?

Comment: No. As a sender, you have no control over what the receiver does.

Comment: I meant hiding myself. Please see the update.

Answer (score 1):

As @greg-hewgill already mentioned in the comments, the `Received:`-header is added by every mail server which handles a mail and places there information where and when the mail came from. For example, here're some lines ([from one of my posts at serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/649674/217116)):

```
Received: from scipy.org (unknown [216.62.213.231])
    by hostname.example.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0ED6022427
    for <user@example.net>; Fri,  5 Dec 2014 14:30:18 +0100 (CET)
Received: from scipy.org (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by scipy.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id CA29E327C6;
    Fri,  5 Dec 2014 07:30:07 -0600 (CST)
Received: from plane.gmane.org (plane.gmane.org [80.91.229.3])
    by scipy.org (Postfix) with ESMTP id 1D4FD32728
    for <numpy-discussion@scipy.org>; Fri,  5 Dec 2014 07:30:05 -0600 (CST)
```

Thus you need to hide your own IP, if you don't have admin rights for the mailserver you are using (then it's easy to solve). This is typical application of anonymization like with [TOR](https://torproject.org/). You can also go with a VPN (Virtual Private Network), thus tunnelling all your internet data through a secure channel to some other endpoint of your VPN provider and showing the mailserver this IP instead of your private one.

But you need to make sure, that in both variants, the client could reveal more informations, like it's version and other things. So to be fully anonymous, there are more steps to take. But it's not the right place here and I'm sure you'll find enough information in the internet. Otherwise, ask your specific question on [Information Security @ SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).